# Loading Corresponding HTML page of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the set of images in the drop down list when I select an image from it the corresponding image is getting loaded.

My problem is if I click over the image it has to take me to the corresponding HTML page of the image. I am performing it in jQuery. I have represented the code below and you can also refer this link  http://www.olivepropertyglobalsolutions.com/

HTML:

```
<div class = "right">
  <h4 class = "heading"> Browse Listings </h4>
  <select style = "margin-top: 55px; margin-left: 18px;" name="image" id="image1" class="inputbox" size="1">
    <option value=""> - Select - </option>
    <option value="thumbs/3.jpg" >Farm Lands</option>
    <option value="thumbs/1.jpg" alt = "flat.html">Flats</option>
    <option value="thumbs/2.jpg" alt = "house.html">Houses</option>
    <option value="thumbs/4.jpg" alt = "vacant.html">Vacant Lands</option>
    <option value="thumbs/5.jpg" alt = "villa.html">Villas</option>
  </select>
  <div style = "margin-left: 14px;">
    <a id="imagePreview" href = ""> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image1").change(function() {
      $("#imagePreview").empty();
      if ( $("#image1").val()!="" ) {
        $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" + $("#image1").val()  + "\" />");
      } else {
        $("#imagePreview").append("");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class = "right">
  <h4 class = "heading"> Browse Listings </h4>
  <select style = "margin-top: 55px; margin-left: 18px;" name="image" id="image1" class="inputbox" size="1">
    <option value=""> - Select - </option>
    <option value="farm-land" >Farm Lands</option>
    <option value="flats" alt = "flat.html">Flats</option>
    <option value="house" alt = "house.html">Houses</option>
    <option value="vacant" alt = "vacant.html">Vacant Lands</option>
    <option value="villas" alt = "villa.html">Villas</option>
  </select>        
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image1").change(function() {
      $("#imagePreview").empty();
      if ( $("#image1").val()!="" ) {
        window.location.href = "http://domain/" + $(this).val() + ".html";
      } else {
        //anything
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

**NOTE: give only page name without `.html` in value of options in select 
`.html/.php/any extension` and site URL can append in JS**

### New Requirement

add image and its link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#image1").change(function() {
          $("#imagePreview").empty();
          if ( $("#image1").val()!="" ) {
            "$("#imagePreview").append("<a src="http://domain/" + $(this).val() + ".html"> <img src=\"" + $(this).attr("alt");  + "\" /></a>");
          } else {
            //anything
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

### NOTE

may be syntex is some how wrong but the way is this

Comment: @ Sahil Thanks!.Its working but the thing is if the drop down is clicked its taking directly to the corresponding page.But I need the image to be displayed and then by clicking the image the corresponding page should get loaded!

Comment: wait a min i ll see if it is possible

Comment: Thank you! Let me try and will post you the result!

Comment: ok and if done mark it as answer that somebody else see can identify

Answer (score 0):

please check this jQuery code:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#image1").change(function() {
                $("#imagePreview").empty();
                if ( $("#image1").val()!="" ){
                    var url = $("#image1 option:selected").attr('alt');
                    alert(url);
                    $("#imagePreview").attr('href',url);
                    $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" +$("#image1").val()  + "\" />");
                }
                else{
                    $("#imagePreview").append("");
                }
            });
        });
```

In this code `$("#image1 option:selected").attr('alt');` will return the 'alt' attribute value of selected item of dropdown. With the help of `<a href="">` you can give link to corresponding HTML page.

Comment: @ Sagar...Tried with your code just getting a thumbnail and when clicked over it redirecting to home page!

Comment: I have edited some part, Check alert, is it showing correct url? if not then preappend the string domain name to 'url' variable. I have tried it and it's working fine for me.

Comment: I have not noticed that 'imagePreview' is an anchor tag. now i have edited code on the basic of that. Check out the new solution. It should work..In that use your given select tag with 'alt' attribute .. because of that it is redirecting to home page.